# Angle to get an "2:1 isometric" camera view (dimetric projection)?

Tags: rendering, camera, orthographic

Most isometric games do not use "**true isometry**", but a **2:1 projection**.(In fact, this is not an isometry but dimetric projection)
I found soooo many articles on how to set up true isometric (with 54.736). **But how to get an 2:1 projection view?**

Rotating the camera 60 degrees seems to give almost a 2:1 projection, but quite a bit incorrect. I was comparing screenshots in Photoshop, but there seems to be a slight deviation.
Maybe am I wrong, and to get a 2:1 projection, the angle of rotation of the camera in X axis should be 60?
I will be very grateful for your answers. I would like to deal with this completely.

Because there is a lot of confusion with this topic and some articles here only confused me even more [Setting up an isometric view](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135306/setting-up-an-isometric-view)

And when I was looking for examples, I noticed that some games use their own angles orthographic projection, which is only found in them. Perhaps that's why there is so much confusion.

Comment: I think I found the answer by accident. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/74782/rendering-models-in-isometric-view

I just looked for information about the ""2: 1" isometric projection", without reference to the Blender or to the camera angle, and found information just about the camera angle.
As if the correct angle of rotation for "2: 1" is still 60 degrees ... 

Before that, I tried to figure it out several times, but I got even more confused.

Comment: Also  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_video_game_graphics  suggesting ortho camera at `location = (2, -2, sqrt(3))` and `rotation_euler_in_degrees =  (60, 0, 45)` looking at default cube.  _ie accepted answer in linked q was 2.5D, the correction for true isometric_

Comment: Related: [Isometric 30° seems to behave like dimetric 26.6°](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/139469/60486)

Answer (score 1):

There is a free add-on called Create IsoCam, apparently "migrating" according to the Wiki.  Seems to work fine in version 2.93.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I've heard about this addon. I just would like to sort out the theory to understand what I am doing.
I just started to deal with isometry (I draw 2D art, and make models in a blender to paint them later). I didn't notice before that many games use their tilt angle for dimetry. I would like to understand how the camera tilt angle and the angle in the orthogonal projection depend.